# Why does a group show up in the “Users & Groups” GUI but not in “/etc/groups/” in macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, user-groups

I have in macOS in “Users & Groups” I have a group called: `access_bpf`.

[image: Users & Groups Photo]

But it is not in: `/etc/groups`

Where is the user of `accesss_bpf` and how does not the other groups show in the “Users & Groups” GUI.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138694/what-is-access-bpf-group

Comment: Do you mean /etc/group? As the comment at the beginning of it says, it's only used in single-user mode; the regular group info is managed by Open Directory (which keeps it in files in /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups/).

Comment: Yeah /etc/group. Cleared much but not yet solved because: i don't know why the user access_bpf is created other way and what is the difference.